# Spring AOP for restful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-aop

I am refering to Spring AOP by Mkyong http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-example-pointcut-advisor/

It worked when tried running from main (i.e. App.java) as given on above link,

I want to integrate it in restful webservice where i have multiple service like CutomerService in mkyong's example.

For example i have controller which calls CustomerService,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class CustomerController{

@Autowired CustomerService customerService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET")
    public ResponseEntity<CommonResponse> getService(){
        customerService.printName();
    }
}
```

It didn't worked.

i have tried this also:

```
@Autowired
private ProxyFactoryBean customerServiceProxy;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET")
    public ResponseEntity<CommonResponse> getService(){
    CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService) customerServiceProxy
                    .getTargetSource().getTarget();
        customerService.printName();
    }
}
```

this dosent work either.

Any Solution for this?

my bean-config.xml is same as mkyong's example.

Comment: Can your clarify: Would you like to run it on some Application Server instead of main method? What is not working? Please bring stack trace.

Comment: I am running it on tomcat, and the service will be called as a rest endpoint.

Comment: Ok, how did you configure Spring context in Tomcat server? Is it not working because context is not starting or injected beans are null or anything else?

Comment: It worked after changing config, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked ! Just need to change proxy class from "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean" to
"org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator"

Auto proxy creator identifies beans to proxy via a list of names. So we don,t need to specify target bean instead list of beans can be specified and it will intercept automatically.
My config look as below:

```
<bean id="adviceAround" class="com.tdg.ess.semantic.event.log.AdviceAround" />
    <!-- Event logging for Service -->
    <bean id="testServicePointCut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcut">
        <property name="mappedNames">
            <list>
                <value>process</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="testServiceAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor">
        <property name="pointcut" ref="testServicePointCut" />
        <property name="advice" ref="adviceAround" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="beanNames">
            <list>
            <!-- Differnt beans which have certain service defined like CustomerService-->
                <value>testService1</value>
                <value>testService2</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>testServiceAdvisor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Thanks everyone for looking into.